# Selecting and Modifying blank space

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to do is select and modify a blank space.

For example, if you look at my excel file that I have posted, I have highlighted the cells of interest;
If you look at column A you will notice attributes like (CON####) - CON1736, or CON1276, etc.

What I need to do it assign a string variable "TH" in the blank spaces (in column B).

To understand my goal please view attached image label final outcome.

Hope to hear back someone soon.

Cheers

[image: final outcome]

[image: PLease view my excel problem]

Comment: This can be done through a very simple build-in function. You really don't need VBA for this if you don't want to. Also please include your own code too

Comment: in terms of a built in function, are you referring to something like a table?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], to e.g see that data should be  provided as [text-table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) not picture!

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, without VBA:

- Select `B1:B?`, basically whichever is your last row
- Goto tab `Start` > Select `Find & Select` > Choose `Go To Special` > Choose `Blanks`
- Now all empty cells in your range are selected with cursor in top one. Type `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CON????",A4)),"TH","")` and hit key-combo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

You might want to copy/paste `B:B` to values